# Насколько корректен такой подход к вёрстке? Bootstrap4

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap4

Верстаю на bootstrap, но меня терзают сомнения насчёт правильности моего подхода. Прошу подсказать, насколько объективна такая вложенность элементов и каким образом можно выравнять элементы по вертикали, не задавая принудительно высоту блоку с классом row?

Пример кода:

```
<section class="container-fluid top-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center tm-height">
            <div class="col-md-3 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Задачи:

1. У каждой секции свой background-color.
2. Секции должны быть отцентрированы по центру.
3. Контент (текст, изображения) должны быть отцентрированы по вертикали.

Вопросы:

1. Насколько корректно решать задачу №1 следующей структурой?

```
.container-fluid > .container ?
```

Может есть более простое решение?

2. Насколько корректна следующая вложенность элементов? Мне не нравится, что до контента аж 3 "обёртки", или это в порядке вещей?

```
.container-fluid > .container > .row
```

3. Чтобы отцентрировать по вертикали я добавляю к обёртке контента

```
.row
```

класс

```
align-items-center
```

НО, для этого необходимо блоку с .row принудительно указывать высоту (добавляю класс .tm-height)

Насколько это правильный подход? Может, есть свойство, которое автоматически придаёт .row высоту родительского элемента?

Answer (score 0):

Для центровки лучше подойдет flexbox

Comment: почитаю, спасибо, а в целом по остальным моментам скажете чего?)

Comment: Да, такая структура приемлема